# Download a file from a website in command line in Linux

Tags: linux, curl, wget, lynx

I need to download a file from a website which has a URL formatted like:

```
http://www.server.com/downloads/1234/
```

This redirects to a .zip file which has to be saved. There is also a need to authenticate based on username and password.

I tried to use `wget`, `curl` and `lynx` with no luck.

*UPDATE:*

- `wget` doesnt work with redirection. It simply downloads the webpage instead of the zip file.
- `curl` gives the error "Maximum redirection exceeded  > 50 "
- `lynx` also gives the same error.

Comment: Are you getting errors or is it simply not working?

Comment: How did you invoke lynx/curl/wget? What error did you get?

Comment: I have updated the question..

Comment: If you have to log in and then the site redirects then you'll have to authenticate (submit your user/pass), probably a POST, then use the cookie the is returned in the next request.  The curl error you're getting is probably you missing a parameter or cookie in the redirection (e.g. they set a Session cookie and you're not passing it on the redirection so it redirect you away, then redirect you back...infinite loop perhaps???).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wget does support redirect, does this work?

```
wget --user=USER --password=PASS --max-redirect URL
```

Note that if the site does not implement HTTP Authentication (require a form submission via GET or POST), *then* you'll need to setup some more work (given the little information you give about the site where the file is, a good answer is hard to give)

```
wget --post-file=datafile --keep-session-cookies --max-redirect URL
```

and your `datafile` could look like

```
username=USER
password=PASS
```

where `username` and `password` should be the name of the form fields being submitted.

**NOTE :** the site needs to redirect to the actual Zip file and not some other page where there is a link to the Zip file. If this is the case, you'll need to write a parsing script because neither Curl or Wget will help you there. They are tools to get content off of a given Url, they are not meant to "guess" you want you want them to fetch; they simply download what the server sends.